# Creating strike-through in Word document with C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm attempting to create a word document, but text between certain words should be crossed out. I tried looking online for solutions but the only solution I could find was:

```
Set myRange = document.Range(Start:= document.Words(1).Start, _End:= document.Words(3).End)
myRange.Font.StrikeThrough = True
```

from here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/font-strikethrough-property-word for VBA. Unfortunately there was nothing for C#.

Does anyone know how you would add a strike-through to specific pieces of text before saving it all to a word document?

*My code for reference:*

```
//input is a StringBuilder received by method  
 try {
            //Create an instance for word app
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application winword = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

            //Set animation status for word application
            winword.ShowAnimation = false;

            //Set status for word application is to be visible or not.
            winword.Visible = false;

            //Create a missing variable for missing value
            object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            //Create a new document
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = winword.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);


            //adding text to document
            document.Content.SetRange(0, 0);
            document.Content.Text = input.ToString();


            //Save the document
            object filename = @"C:\Users\TempUser\Desktop\temp1.docx";
            document.SaveAs2(ref filename);
            document.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            document = null;
            winword.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            winword = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Document created successfully!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._font.strikethrough.aspx

Comment: @itsme86 thank you. I'm not sure why my searches didn't turn that up.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: @CindyMeister yes it did! Thank you
Sorry I have under 15 reputation so I can't provide you any votes.

Comment: No worries :-) The checkmark is important: 1) The question won't be removed; 2) Others with the same problem will find it more easily; 3) Those who might consider answering will know it's been answered. I expect you'll get to 15 soon enough... Enjoy!

Comment: Oh I see! Again, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've extracted the relevant part from your code to make it easier to follow.

My assumption with this sample is that text should be inserted at the end of the document and formatted as "strikethrough". Notice how I declare a `Word.Range` object and assign the body of the document to it. For understanding how it works, think of a Range like a Selection, but you can have more than one and it's not visible in the document.

The next line "collapses" the Range to its end-point - like pressing Right arrow. If you did *not* collapse the Range, the text assigned to it would *replace* what's in the document (like over-typing a selection). The text is then assigned to the Range and the Strikethrough applied.

Note that in the old Word Basic days "true" and "false" were not concepts used for setting font decoration. Word's object model still uses these old Word Basic commands. Under the covers they still use -1 for true and 0 for false (and sometimes 1 for something else). While the VB languages can use the "pseudo boolean" settings (true/false) that have been added to the object model for convenience, C# doesn't "see" them, so you need -1 for true.

```
    //adding text to document
    object oCollapseEnd = Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd;
    Word.Range rng = document.Content;
    rng.Collapse(ref oCollapseEnd);
    rng.Text = input.ToString();
    rng.Font.Strikethrough = -1;  // 0 for false
```